# Mac OS X Leopard: Install on External from Lion or Mountain Lion

Tags: installation, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, osx-leopard

I'm trying to set up some testing machines on an external hard drive. I have a Lion MBP and Mountain Lion MBP, and I'm trying to perform the installations from mac books.

When I attemt to run the Leopard installer on both machines, I get a failed install with the message "The application 'Install Mac OS X' cannot be used from this volume. To install Mac OS X, please use the application provided on the Mac OS X installation disc."

[image: Leopard failed install run]

According to the setup instructions for a customized installation (page 4), all I need to do is click the icon and wait for a reboot. it looks like another bug missed by Apple QA.

The error message tells me to use my installation disc. As Apple does not provide installations discs, it looks like another bug missed by Apple QA.

Does anyone know how to work around all these Apple screw ups? All I want to do is install the damn OS on an external drive.

+1 to Apple QA for another job well done.

Comment: generally installing older operating systems on newer computers leads to bugs. Is this MBP from the osx leopard era or before?

Comment: I'm confused here -- the "Leopard installer" application normally comes on the installer DVD, and it's really just a stub that reboots the Mac from the DVD so the real installer can run. How did you get the app without the rest of the disc?

Comment: I copied the *.DMG to the hard drive so it would not get lost in my travels.  Its now in storage about 300 miles away.

Comment: You're going to need to restore/burn that .dmg to a partition or DVD, so that you can boot from it. As @agovizer points out, you'll also need an old enough Mac to run the old OS (both for the install, and the actual operation).